# Linking SqlDataSource to label for a single item in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a `asp:SqlDataSource` that returns a single row. How do I return that value into a label. I got it working in a `asp:DataList` but its overkill since its a single record.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT  STATEMENT">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:DataList ID="DataList5" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: What about making a property on your page that runs the select statement, and returns the result as a string? Then you could bind your Text on lblGradTerm to that property, right?

Comment: Do you have a link to an example that uses this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24169177/1804496 my answer below is the only example I have.

Comment: please note that it is inconsiderate to delete a question after you have received a legitimate answer for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it in **C#:**

```
DataView oDV = (System.Data.DataView)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

Label1.Text = string.Join("|", oDV.Table.Rows[0].ItemArray.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: This looks so much easier to implement than my suggestion. Especially since he already has the SqlDataSource set up. My only suggestion is to use the `.Join` method on string http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx like `Label1.Text = String.Join(",", oDV.Table.Rows[0].ItemArray)` instead of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

I guess my project is using an actual method instead of a property like I first suggested.

You could use a [text SqlCommand(String, SqlConnection)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a.aspx), passing the select statement and a [SqlConnection(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0.aspx) to your database.

```cs
public string GetSelectStatement()
{
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
  string selectStatement = "SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Customer";
  SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, conn);
  comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
  SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
  
  // My code has a While loop, but you shouldn't need it with only one record
  reader.Read();
  string ID = (string)reader["ID"];
  return ID;
}
```

Then in your page (aspx) or control (ascx) you can use that method to bind the label text...

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetSelectStatement() %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: I'm using vb but this was fine. How would you pass a var through the asp side into the get method?